# Current time between two hours

Tags: php, date, time, range, hour

My site has "StartHour" and "EndHour"

**Example:**

If the current time (1500) is between the **StartHour(0800)** and **EndHour(2300)** the site works, then:

```
    $currentTime= date('Hi');
    $startTime= $setting_info['start_hour']; // 
    $endTime=  $setting_info['end_hour']; //
if($currentTime>=$startTime && $currentTime<=$endTime) 
    {
    echo "Site Works Perfectly";
    }
```

The problem is when the `$endTime` is bigger than 2359 for example, I want that my site works from 0800 to 0200. It won't work because if `$currenttime` is 1000 it will be bigger than `$startTime` but will be bigger than `$endTime` too.

Or if `$currenttime` is 0000 it will be smaller than `$starttime` and smaller than `$endtime`.

I can't figure out how to solve this.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Use it like below:

```
<?php
 $currentTime= time();
$startTime= "08:00:00";
$endTime=  "22:00:00";
 $startTime=strtotime(date('Y-m-d '.$startTime));
 strtotime($startTime);
$endTime=strtotime(date('Y-m-d '.$endTime));
if($currentTime>=$startTime && $currentTime<=$endTime) 
    {
    echo "Site Works Perfectly";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert  the Time Strings to timestamps with `strtotime()` and compare them with `thime()`

```
$st_time    =   strtotime($setting_info['start_hour']);
$end_time   =   strtotime($setting_info['end_hour']);
$cur_time   =   strtotime(now);

if($st_time < $cur_time && $end_time > $cur_time)
{
   echo "WE ARE CLOSE NOW !!";
}
else{
   echo "WE ARE OPEN  NOW !!";
}
```